# Cannot push to artifactory docker cloud repository

Tags: docker, cloud, artifactory

I have an artifactory cloud account, and it is supposed to support docker repositories, I have set up an nginx proxy and everything looks ok, but I get a problem when pushing docker reports a 405 error, what I've seen is that it doesn't support the PUT method.

Here are the command and response:

```
docker push 10.0.2.2:8443/proxy
The push refers to a repository [10.0.2.2:8443/proxy] (len: 1)
7cad47f9dd1b: Image push failed 
Error pushing to registry: Server error: 405 trying to push proxy blob - sha256:a40574043c2db30c7d0fbac107dda7d592efd479c3c1204c481e76cea2ed1ecc
```

And this is the relevant nginx config

```
server {
       listen       8443 ssl;
       server_name  localhost;

       ssl on;
       ssl_certificate /Users/iamedu/Development/gextech/cherry/ops/docker/proxy/cert/server.crt;
       ssl_certificate_key /Users/iamedu/Development/gextech/cherry/ops/docker/proxy/cert/server.key;

       access_log logs/access.log;
       error_log logs/error.log;

       proxy_set_header Host gextech.artifactoryonline.com;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
       proxy_set_header      Authorization "Basic AHARCODEDTOKEN";

       proxy_read_timeout 900;


       client_max_body_size 0;

       chunked_transfer_encoding on;

       location /v2 {
         dav_methods PUT DELETE;
         if ($http_user_agent ~ "^(docker\/1\.(3|4|5(?!\.[0-9]-dev))|Go ).*$" ) {
           return 404;
         }
         proxy_pass http://anaccount.artifactoryonline.com/anaccount/api/docker/local-docker/v2;
       }

}
```

Comment: Did you try already to add `POST` to the `dav_methods`?

Comment: The default v2 local Docker repository name in Artifactory online is dockerv2-local

Comment: POSTS are fin, it's the PUT that sends 405

Comment: I created the local-docker repository, shouldn't it work that way?